# How to manipulate axios returned data to print in desired formate

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
    <template>
    <div>

        <table class="table table-responsive">

            <tbody>


            <tr  v-for="(gameresults, index) in gameresults" :key="index">

              <td style="color: #082ad4; font-size: 24px;">{{ gameresults.game_name }}</br>
               <h3 style="color:#00d2f1; font-size: 18px;">{{ gameresults.cards }}</h3></td>
                <h3 style="color:#00d2f1; font-size: 18px;">{{ this.formattedArray }}</h3></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div></template>

<script>
export default {
    props: [''],

    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    },
    data() {
        return {
            gameresults:0,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        changeResult() {

                let formattedArray = [];
            this.gameresults.cards.forEach(str => {
                    const subs = str.split('');
                    const subsTwo = subs[2].split(',');
                    const formattedString = `${subs[1]} - ${subs[0]}-${subsTwo[0]}${subs[4]}-${subsTwo[1]}`;
                    formattedArray.push(formattedString);
                });
                console.log('Formatted Data', formattedArray);
            }

           // this.gameresults[0].cards


    },
    computed: {
        chkgameresults() {

            axios.post('/gameresults')
                .then(response => {
                     this.gameresults = response.data ;
                     this.changeResult();
                    
                });
        },


    },

    created () {
        this.chkgameresults();
    }
};
</script>
```

ref code axios fetches mysql concat data in array format having 2 keys [game_name and card ] i want card key to be manipulated . when i print  card array using  this.gameresults[0].card its giving me  123-9,897-0 using  {{ gameresults.cards }} inside vu template , i want  value to get manipulated like 123-90-897 (  only last 0 gets before the second exp and become 0-897 removing ',' separator

Comment: I need only to manipulate last 4 number to print in reverse order 
{{ mydata.myvalue }}
122-5,147-2
should get printed as below
122-5,2-147

Comment: Mydata.myvalue....is that an array?

Comment: No its not array its coming inside one single data field

Comment: Then you need to use NLP only

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is an array lets define a method...........

```
formatData(myData) {
  let formattedArray = [];
  myData.myValue.forEach(str => {
   const subs = str.split('');
   const subsTwo = subs[2].split(',');
   const formattedString = `${subs[1]} - ${subs[0]}-${subsTwo[0]}${subs[4]}-${subsTwo[1]}`;
   formattedArray.push(formattedString);
 });
 console.log('Formatted Data', formattedArray);
}
```

Comment: now i only need  following data which i'm getting with one filed as a concat value i.e [ 136-0 ] , [ 150-6 ]  i just want this to get printed [ 136-06-150 ] this ways in which value which i'm receiving via field should be revered for second concat and it will appear [ 136-06-150 ]   in which 6 is reversed before 150.

Comment: Please add these changes to your question so that it ll be more clear

Comment: ' methods: {
        changeResult() {

                let formattedArray = [];
            this.gameresults.cards.forEach(str => {
                    const subs = str.split('');
                    const subsTwo = subs[2].split(',');
                    const formattedString = `${subs[1]} - ${subs[0]}-${subsTwo[0]}${subs[4]}-${subsTwo[1]}`;
                    formattedArray.push(formattedString);
                });
                console.log('Formatted Data', formattedArray);
            }'

this.gameresults[0].cards is giving me 123-5, 456-9  but i want 123-5 9-456 plz help.

Comment: Please update the same in the question as the tried out  so that it will be more readable

Comment: Moreover pls update the data over which you are iterating...so that I ll have my answer updated

Comment: could you please update your answer checking updated question